# MVC Passing Model Data into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

So I am trying to pass the data (int-Array) from my Model...

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models {
    public class Sudoku {
        public int[] numbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

..., initialized with indices by the Controller ...

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class SudokuController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Sudoku/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Sudoku sudoku = new Sudoku();

            int[] numbers = new int[81];
            for (var i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
                numbers[i] = i;
            }
            sudoku.numbers = numbers;

            return View(sudoku);
        }
    }
}
```

... through the View ...

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Sudoku
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sudoku";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Sudoku</h1>

<div class="sudoku"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script id="script1" src="~/Scripts/render_sudoku.js" type="text/javascript" data-numbers=@Model.numbers></script>
}
```

... into my JavaScript file, where I just want to use it as an array.

However, when I try

`console.log($('#script1').data("numbers"));`,

I only get

`System.Int32[]`

as an answer, which seems to be a String only describing the format.

Is it possible to work with the actual Array in the JavaScript file?

I'm new to MVC and can't quite get the grasp of it.

Comment: What do you get with this instead? : `console.log($('#script1').data("numbers")[0]);`

Comment: Try `console.log($('#script1').data("numbers").join());` (look [JavaScript join()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp))

Comment: @Crowcoder This returns `S`, so just the first letter of the String.

Comment: @Rafalon That gives me `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).join is not a function`, I guess because it isn't an array?

Comment: becuase @Model.numbers is List of int objects so it display its string value you cant access like this

Comment: Lalji is right, try using `data-numbers='@String.Join(",",Model.numbers")'` then split it in your javascript to have it as an array ([C# String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you pass the list of numbers as a variable inside the scripts-section, instead of setting it as a data-attribute of the tag inside it. You can then use the variable in you script.

**In your view:**

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        var mynumbers = "@string.Join(",", Model.numbers)";
    </script>
    <script id="script1" src="~/Scripts/render_sudoku.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

**In your script:**

```
var numbers = mynumbers.split(",");
for (var i in numbers)
{
    var number = numbers[i];
    // DO WHATEVER
}
```

Edit: You need to put the declaration of the Javascript variable inside quotes, or otherwise you will get an ESLint parsing error.

Comment: Couldn't it work this way without joining and splitting? `var mynumbers = @Model.numbers`?

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure, it could work, haven't tried it. But that would indeed save the two extra operations.

Edit: That would probably not work. ESLint will throw a parsing error on the line declaring the variable, expecting a string.

Comment: @Rafalon you can directly set your javascript variable as array  var sudokuNumbers = [@string.Join(",", Model.numbers);] so not required to split

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! I didn't know I could declare a global variable in the scripts-section of the View and use it in my external script.

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: @Model.numbers is List of int objects so it display its string value you cant access like this, because it convert into object string.

Solution: Above answer is right but if you want to access direct JavaScript variable as array like below,
You can set int string array to java-script variable like below.

```
   <script>
        var sudokuNumbers = [@string.Join(",", Model.numbers)]
   </script>
```

Not require to split string into array in JavaScript.

now you can access `sudokuNumbers`, this variable is javascript array.
and you can access its value.
i hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm puzzled concerning that `;` as I think it will not be considered as part of `@`

Comment: @Rafalon yes right by typo mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it IMO is through a serializer from the Framework that can process just about anything, not only arrays. That way you never have to worry about details of the formatting, escape sequences, special cases etc.

In the View:

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
}
<script>
    var numbers = @Html.Raw(serializer.Serialize(Model.numbers));
</script>
```